# Need to show the trajectory of the line connecting all points in Matplotlib but need to code in C

Tags: c, matplotlib

I am working on this school project where we need to code in C to connect all points using a Rover. There is this one function already provided called RoverCmd and here is the explanation for it provided from the teacher

The top speed of the rover is 1 meter/second. The RoverCmd() function takes two values, one for the left wheel speed and one for the right wheel speed. The range of possible values is from -100 (full reverse) to 100 (full forward). Assigning different values to each side will cause the rover to turn. Each call to RoverCmd() represents 0.1 seconds of time, so RoverCmd(100, 100) will move the rover forward 0.1 meters.

and here is my code so far with the picture of the output

```
double angle(Point a, Point b)
{
    double ang = atan2((b.y- a.y),  (b.x - a.x))*(180/PI);
    if (ang < 0)
    {
        RoverCmd(100, -100);
    }
    else
    {
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
    }
    
    return ang;
    
}
double magnitude(Point a, Point b)
{
    
        int mag = sqrt((b.x - a.x) * (b.x - a.x) + (b.y - a.y) * (b.y - a.y));
        
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        return mag;
    
}




void Simulate(Point path[], int count, FILE* outputFile)
{       
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(-100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);     
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);
        RoverCmd(100, 100);

        



        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
        
            for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
            {
                angle(path[i], path[j]);
                
                magnitude(path[i], path[j]);
                

                path[i] = path[j];
                path[j] = path[i++];
                

                
            }
        }
    
        
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main()
{
    Point path[MAX_PATH];

    // Open the output file for writing
    FILE* outputFile = fopen("MarsRover.csv", "wt");
    if (!outputFile)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open output file.\n");
        keypress();
        return 0;
    }

    // Initialize the simulator
    Init(outputFile);
    int count = ReadPath("path.csv", path, MAX_PATH);  
    

    // Run the simulation
    Simulate(path, count, outputFile);

    // Close the output file
    fclose(outputFile);

    system("python roverPlot.py MarsRover.csv path.csv mars.png");
    return 0;
}
```

MatPlotLib
[image]

As you can see thats all I can do I can't to make it connect between the two points please help me

Comment: [LERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)?

Comment: You need to connect _every_ point? Is this supposed to be some kind of path-optimization exercise? You only made it that far and you've already got a billion calls to `RoverCmd`, time to start thinking in loops.

Comment: I think the idea is to have a function that calculates the direction to the next point from your current heading, one that translates that direction into wheel spin intensities to turn it appropriately, and finally another that calculates the distance to the point and loops enough to get there. But how you're going to visit every point, much less optimally, I have no idea. Interesting problem.

Comment: The teacher forgot to explain how fast the rover rotates when the wheels are moving at different speeds.

Comment: @user3386109 The top speed is 1 meter/sec

Comment: That doesn't tell you how fast the rover rotates. The rotation rate depends on the size of the rover.